# Is it always necessary to discharge the filter capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier

Consider, for example, a bypass capacitor that can be replaced without having to disassemble the PCB board to access the filter capacitors.
The capacitor in question has an accumulated voltage, tested with a multimeter, of a few mV.
Is it safe to remove this component without discharging the filter capacitors?
Because the common rule is that before working on the components of an amplifier it is necessary to discharge the filter caps.

Comment: You will remove power to the PCB before replacing the capacitor right?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose by "filter capacitor", you a referring to the capacitors of the AC to DC converter.

If so, if you know nothing about the actual circuit, always assume the worst (ie the capacitors are charged to about the peak to peak voltage (ie twice the amplitude) of your mains (ie 2×110V or 2×230V depending where you live). So you really don't want to get in contact with such voltage (particularly if the capacitors are big). So if in doubt, always discharge the capacitors first (excepted if you really don't have the choice, then get proper training to work under voltage, and get adequate protective equipment : I strongly advise against this option).

If you know the circuit, you might be able to know that there is neither significant voltage, nor significant energy in the capacitors, and you might be able to skip the discharging step : but this requires extensive knowledge of the power stage of your amplifier, in order to be sure it is safe.

Comment: I have measured the voltage of every capacitors, except two electrolytic caps ("filter" caps) which I do not have access to from the front of the PCB. There is no voltage.
Let's say I want to replace a ceramic or film capacitor that has a voltage of a few millivolts.
Can I do it?
But I want to make it even simpler.
Let's say that for whatever reason I haven't checked or discharged the filter caps, but I decide to remove a non-electrolytic capacitor that has no voltage on it.
Can there be a flow of electric current from a charged capacitor to a discharged one?

Comment: I must specify that the two inaccessible capacitors (from the front of the PCB) are the Power supply filter caps. So I haven't measured their voltage yet.

Comment: The uncharged capacitor shouldn't get charged by "magic". So the uncharged capacitor is likely (but without knowing the circuit itself no way to be certain) to be safe as a standalone part. But you might still have other tracks/components nearby (which ones are hard to know without schematics + layout), that are connected to the high voltage from the filter caps : if you happen to touch those, you will still get an electrical shock. I'm not going to do any soldering a few cm from a part (potentially) charged at several hundreds volts. I would advise you don't risk it either

Comment: As a rule of thumb : consider a circuit with charged filter capacitors the same way as if it were still plugged into mains : that way, you stay safe.

Comment: Everyone recommends to discharge the power supply filter caps, even if as you say "the uncharged capacitor shouldn't get charged by magic".
The two statements contradict each other, but for lack of a clearer answer I'll discharge those capacitors.

Comment: The uncharged capacitor itself is safe. But nearby components/tracks might be unsafe. So if you touch only the uncharged capacitor, you are fine, but if by accident you touch a nearby component (quite likely) you might get a choc from the charged capacitor.

Comment: The same way, when you change a light bulb, you make sure that electricity is turned off, even if you only plan to touch the plastic/glass parts of the bulb which are "safe" : but if you touch some metal parts you will get a choc, unless you turn electricity off. So I hope you do turn everything off before changing the light. Similarly, people discharge filter capacitors before touching anything nearby.

Comment: I don't have to work near the power caps; furthermore they are protected by an enclosure. There are also bleeder resistors in parallel to discharge the same capacitors when the amp is off (which is why I couldn't find any voltage). Anyway I'm just an amateur who wants to make some mods; so it's better to get some info before doing something wrong.

Comment: That's a lot of new information. If the whole converter block is in a full enclosure, and there is only ever low voltage outside this enclosure, you are probably fine. If you know there are bleeding resistors, and you know the values of those resistors and the capacity of the capacitors, then you can compute the duration after which you know the capacitors should be empty (provided the bleeding resistors are fine). I would suggest you share pictures and schematics if you want more detailed guidance for this specific situation

Comment: Okay sorry.
However I'm more interested in general principles, than talking in detail about an amplifier I already know.

Comment: For general principles : always check that filter capacitors are discharged (and discharge them if not) unless either you have enough knowledge about the specific circuit you are working on to be certain that there is no risk, or you are trained and equipped to work near/under voltage (and even then, it is recommended to work near/under voltage only if there is no alternative)

Comment: When you say 'choc' do you mean shock?

Comment: yes, indeed, sorry for the mistake (I used the french word)